# Slow PHP cURL - Sending small base64_encoded image

Tags: php, curl, optimization, php-curl

I'm a posting a cURL request, but somehow it is not that fast. It takes about 6 seconds to finish. Within the cURL, I am sending a base64_encoded small image. 64x64px.

It might not be the image which slows the cURL, but something else. Here is the setup:

```
$url = 'the_URL';    
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
```

This is the result:

```
Array ( 
[url] => the_URL?
[content_type] => application/json 
[http_code] => 200 
[header_size] => 441 
[request_size] => 165 
[filetime] => -1 
[ssl_verify_result] => 0 
[redirect_count] => 0 
[total_time] => 5.665052 
[namelookup_time] => 2.2E-5 
[connect_time] => 0.027501 
[pretransfer_time] => 0.091433 
[size_upload] => 204303 
[size_download] => 1149 
[speed_download] => 202 
[speed_upload] => 36063 
[download_content_length] => 1149 
[upload_content_length] => 204303 
[starttransfer_time] => 0.120824 
[redirect_time] => 0 
[redirect_url] => 
[primary_ip] => IP 
[certinfo] => Array ( ) 
)
```

I think 6 seconds is two slow for a cURL like this.

Do I miss something in my setup?

UPDATE!

No sorry. The file is in a zip, and the zip is base64_encoded. My bad. Today it took like 19 seconds to do the cURL execute.

Unfortunately the function `curl_setopt($curl , CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE , CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);` didn't help at all.

There are two images in the zip. They are both 25kb... So it might not be the thing.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: not a curl or php , most likely a DNS resolutions issue.

Comment: Can you try with 1kb file and then with an image more than 1Mb?

Comment: try this :  `curl_setopt($curl , CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE , CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);` to test out a DNS hypothesis. Also, flush  your DNS caches.
`

Comment: images should't be base64 encoded for web transfer anyway. its a huge waste of ram and bandwidth. just send the raw binary!

Comment: @hanshenrik not every use case allows for this.

Comment: @alistaircol i know, for example, photobucket. they had some fucking retard design the api for uploading images, where its base64 encoded AND json encoded after that.. said programmer should obviously not have been allowed to design the api, imagine the terrabytes of bandwidth his idiot design has wasted (they got over 10 billion images hosted, presumably the vast majority of which has the 33% overhead introduced by base64 during uploading)

Comment: (also, if the average size of all uploaded images are 100 kb, which its not, the majority is bigger, a minority is smaller,
and they had exactly 10 billion images, then
the base64 has costed them 348 Terabytes of bandwidth (not accounting for the individual tcp packets overhead, so it is even more)..  and god knows how many cpu cycles decoding it, which is probably reflected both on their bandwidth bills and electricity bills)